# Сохранение файла из диалогового окна в C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать, своего рода, скачивание файла, который лежит в ресурсах проекта в C# WPF? Видел много способов загрузки из интернета, как вы поняли, мне такой не подходит. Программа не будет иметь доступ в интернет.
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: (1) Спрашиваете у юзера, куда записать через [`SaveFileDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0), (2) получаете `Stream` на ресурс (как именно, зависиит от того, это Resource или EmbeddedResource), (3) копируете `Stream`: `using (var fileStream = File.Create(dialog.FileName)) resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream);`.

Comment: На этот вопрос невозможно дать ответ, потому что вы не рассказали, как вы этот файл в ресурсы положили.

Comment: Спасибо, VladD.папку с docx файлом закинул в проект, перетянул просто. Этого должно хватить, спасибо, буду пробовать